# Unexpected token '.' when run create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a new React app using this command on Windows using Node 16.14

`npx create-react-app my-app`

But it fails with this error `npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'`

From the log, this is the stack trace:

```
28 verbose stack C:\ProgramData\nvm\v16.14.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec:1
28 verbose stack ../workspaces/libnpmexec
28 verbose stack ^
28 verbose stack
28 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
28 verbose stack     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
28 verbose stack     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
28 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
28 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
28 verbose stack     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
28 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
28 verbose stack     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
28 verbose stack     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
28 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v16.14.0\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\exec.js:1:17)
28 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
```

Can you please tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to downgrade npm version.
I had this same, on 16.14.0.
I recommend nvm for changing node version.
For example:
nvm install 14.18.1
nvm use 14.18.1

Answer (score 6):

If you're using nvm, upgrading to the latest version of nvm (1.1.9 at the time of writing), uninstalling the node version and reinstalling it fixes the issue.

[They issued a special patch for that issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4234#issuecomment-1040528646)

Comment: This was me; was on 1.1.17 of nvm and latest LTS node. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the debuglog.js file, line 10, located in the path:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\debuglog\debuglog.js:10
```

The error is quite simple, to fix it change the command that is there as follows `if (!debugs[set�)` to `if (!debugs[set])` and save as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

run the following commands:

```
nvm install --lts (installs the latest LTS version)
```

then

```
nvm install node (installs the latest available version)
```

then

```
nvm node (to use the latest version)
```

then

```
node -v
```

(to see the version / confirm you have the latest version)