# npx create-react-app results in unexpected token '.'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nvm

I am trying to use '`npx create-react-app my_demo_project`' but it results in an error specifying ***"Unexpected token"***.

[image]

**Attempted Solution**

Attempted to resolve the issue by following one of the suggested solution in [Unexpected token '.' when run create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71259175/unexpected-token-when-run-create-react-app) however there was no issue with my debuglog.js file
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by following the following steps

1. Update nvm version to v1.1.10 (https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)
2. npm uninstall 18.12.1
3. npm install 18.12.1